# R dplyr batting data example group_by returns incorrect result

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking at the "window-functions" vignette from the dplyr package, which you can pull up with:

```
vignette("window-functions", package="dplyr")
```

The first example doesn't seem to be producing the correct results.

I type the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(Lahman)

batting <- select(tbl_df(Batting), playerID, yearID, teamID, G, AB:H)
batting <- arrange(batting, playerID, yearID, teamID)
players <- group_by(batting, playerID)

filter(players, min_rank(desc(H)) <= 2 & H > 0)
```

And get:

```
Source: local data frame [32,724 x 7]
Groups: playerID

    playerID yearID teamID   G  AB   R   H
1  aaronha01   1966    ATL 158 603 117 168
2  aaronha01   1970    ATL 150 516 103 154
3  aaronto01   1962    ML1 141 334  54  77
4  aaronto01   1963    ML1  72 135   6  27
5  aaronto01   1965    ML1   8  16   1   3
6  aaronto01   1968    ATL  98 283  21  69
7  aaronto01   1969    ATL  49  60  13  15
8  aaronto01   1970    ATL  44  63   3  13
9   abadan01   2003    BOS   9  17   1   2
10  abadfe01   2012    HOU  37   7   0   1
..       ...    ...    ... ... ... ... ...
```

This is the wrong output for aaronto01, for example. It should be:

```
subset(players, playerID == "aaronto01") %.% filter(min_rank(desc(H)) <= 2 & H > 0)

Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

   playerID yearID teamID   G  AB  R  H
1 aaronto01   1962    ML1 141 334 54 77
2 aaronto01   1968    ATL  98 283 21 69
```

Is there an issue with dplyr? Or can someone pick out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: I get the correct answer. What version are you running? If you are using the current versions of those packages, try starting with a clean session and run it again. The data frame you get should be `Source: local data frame [24,834 x 7]`

Comment: oh I see, you had a mistake that @Arun fixed for you (see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23474962/revisions); those data table guys are so nice n sweet, helping out with dplyr problems

Comment: Ah sorry, that was a mistake I made while typing in the code, but I don't think that's the issue. I'm still getting the same problem.

I'm using Spring Dance (3.1.0) and the latest version of dplyr.

Comment: you don't think the issue is that you arranged players instead of batting?

Comment: I don't think so. Does everything look okay in the code above? I just copy and pasted that and I'm still getting the same result (dplyr is 0.1.3 by the way).

Comment: copy the code above and check your output again. you should be getting the right answer now

Comment: Still getting the same thing. Did you change the code? I've also copied directly from the vignette and I get the same result. I'm stumped.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52049/discussion-between-peter-and-rawr)

Answer (score 1):

For reference:

This bug has been documented for dplyr 0.1.3 and fixed in the development version on Github.

https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/313

In the meantime, install 0.2.0 directly from the repo using devtools.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```