# dplyr show all rows and columns for small data.frame inside a tbl_df

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I force `dplyr` to show all columns and rows of a rather small data.frame. The `ddf` object below, for example:

```
df = data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=c(rep('x', 50), rep('y', 50)), c=sample(1:20, 100, replace=T), d=sample(letters,100, replace=T), e=sample(LETTERS,100,replace=T), f=sample("asdasdasdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd asdfasdfsdfsd", 100, replace=T))
ddf= tbl_df(df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View entire data frame when wrapped in tbl\_df?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188900/view-entire-data-frame-when-wrapped-in-tbl-df)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to still use dplyr and print your dataframe just run

```
print.data.frame(ddf)
ddf
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I was getting angry with `dplyr` therefore I could not see. the solution is simple: `as.data.frame(ddf)`. That is to convert dplyr-backed data.frame to generic data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `print` and adjust the `n` parameter to adjust the number of rows to show.

For example, the following commdands will show 20 rows.

```
print(ddf, n = 20)
```

You can also use the typical `dplyr` pipe syntax.

```
ddf %>% print(n = 20)
```

If you want to show *all* rows, you can use `n = Inf` (infinity).

```
print(ddf, n = Inf)
ddf %>% print(n = Inf)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> You can control the default appearance with options:
>
> options(tibble.print_max = n, tibble.print_min = m): if there are more
>   than n rows, print only the first m rows. Use options(tibble.print_max
>   = Inf) to always show all rows.
>
> options(tibble.width = Inf) will always print all columns, regardless
>   of the width of the screen.